# Tabs page transparent with back ground image

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, ionic4

I have tabs page app. I have a background image like so. How can I have transparent tabs as shown below?

[image]

*home.html*

```
<ion-content class="content" fullscreen>


  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="ion-margin-top row1">
      <ion-col size="12" class="ion-text-center">

      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="ion-margin-top row2">
      <ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let b of buttons;" class="padding">
        <app-home-root [data]="b"></app-home-root>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>

  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

*home.scss*

```
ion-content {
    --background: url('/assets/img/stella/background/background.png') no-repeat 100% 100%;
}
```

*tabs.page.html*

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab-bar class="tab" slot="bottom" translucent="true">
    <ion-tab-button (click)="profileAction()">
      <ion-img [src]="myProfileSrc"></ion-img>
      <ion-label>
        My Profile
      </ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>


    <ion-tab-button (click)="openBooking()">
      <ion-img [src]="bookNowSrc"></ion-img>
      <ion-label>Book Now</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>
  </ion-tab-bar>
</ion-tabs>
```

This is what I have now with `translucent="true"`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Ion-content` doesn't continue under the tabs (this can be seen when you inspect it when you run it in a browser), so making the tabs transparent would only show you the background color of the app. I don't know if it is possible to even make it transparent, but because it makes no difference you could always just apply a background color to `ion-tabs` (the same color as your `ion-content` is).

**Edit:**

And if you want to remove the border too, this should be enough:

```
ion-tab-bar {
    --background: #FFF;
    border-style: none;
}
```

If you still see a border you can always add `border: 0;`.

Comment: Yes, But do you know how to remove that border? `no-border` didn't work?